# How immortal is everyone in the film In Time?

Tags: in-time

In the film *In Time*, several characters mention a number of times about being immortal & how they can only die through accidents (I think). What are the limitations of that immortality? By that I mean, when the Timekeeper Raymond "Ray" Leon (Cillian Murphy) gets shot in the arm, does that injury heal at normal human speed or does it heal instantly or superhumanly fast (like Wolverine or like the Immortals from Highlander)?

Comment: Liked this movie, except for the Bonnie and Clyde part.

Answer (score 19):

There is a scene in the film in which the love interest's father explains that "barring accident or violence" the elite are effectively immortal. This implies that there is still the need for hospitals/ doctors to treat injuries, but that ageing and disease has been eliminated. So Cillian Murphy's character will not have the bullet wound heal any faster than it would without the time-currency.

Comment: So,anything that can kill a "mortal" (a human without the "Time" genetic alterations/ implants, whatever it was) can still kill an "immortal" ?

Comment: @Bubba yeah, right.

Comment: So, they're not true immortals, anyway similar to the novel amortals by matt forbeck ? (For one I know that in the novel, they used cloning tech to stay immortal or amortal as they called it)

Comment: @Bubba yep, nobody there is *really* immortal.

Comment: That sounds a lot like Tolkien's elves in the Hobbit/LotR. Effectively ageless.

Comment: Wait there is a novel of In Time? Like a novel it was based off, or a novelisation?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: Harlan Ellison sued the writer of *In Time* over similarities to one of his old short stories, but dropped the suit after reading the script and speaking with the writer himself, satisfied that it wasn't plagiarising his earlier work. Even though I can't recall the story's name, I don't think that's what Bubba is writing about above though. The novel he mentions is by a different author, for one.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone lives there until he (or she) dies because of murder or decease, etc or until his/her clock runs out of time. When someone dies with some time left, his/ her clock stops and digits on it are greyed out, he dies as a normal person dies. The time from it can't be taken (or recorded) anymore.

Comment: Are you sure about the last sentence? I distinctly remember the leader of the evil time-thughs say "What a waste of time" when he shots a guy with at least 3 months on his clock.

Comment: @STT Actually I thought exactly about this moment, and it seemed to me that time *can* be taken. Whats a reason to kill him then? And "What a waste of time" probably meaner that they are wasting *their* time... You can be right, however.

Comment: @nicael They killed him because he stood up to them, was a threat to their power. They showed that they were willing to kill someone with months on the clock for standing up to them.

Comment: @TimB thx for clarification!

Comment: @STTLCU thx for corrections!